# Is it possible to compare a data set with a published mean and standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, mean, standard-deviation

Is it possible to compare a data set with a published mean and standard deviation?

To be more precise: I have a data set of a clinical trial. I want to compare my data with published data from the literature, where you generally find n, mean and standard deviation.

Can this be performed with a t-test? During my research I found a [web site](http://www.quantitativeskills.com/sisa/statistics/t-test.htm), where I can enter 2 means, 2 standard deviations and 2 numbers of cases. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the t-test can be calculated using mean, standard deviation, and N for each of the two groups.  The formula is, e.g., on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_unequal_sample_sizes.2C_equal_variance).  GraphPad (which is well regarded for statistics) has an online [QuickCalc](http://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/ttest1.cfm) for the t-test where one can choose different data entry formats.

Re: whether using the t-test is appropriate in your case, the GraphPad Statistics Guide has a [checklist](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/7/statistics/index.htm?stat_checklist_unpairedttest.htm) for the t-test.  Some of the points of the checklist are actually quite subtle; e.g., the "errors independent" assumption is violated in many papers.  One comment on the Gaussian (normality) assumption: the t-test can typically be used even for non-normal data if the sample sizes are large enough, see Minitab's [advice](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/choosing-between-a-nonparametric-test-and-a-parametric-test).

GraphPad's QuickCalc also has Welch's t-test, which does not require "equal variance."  While GraphPad claims it is used rarely, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test#Advantages_and_limitations) is quite positive, and I like using it since it "takes care of equal variance."

Comment: You are welcome.  Also, just improved the answer a little.